# include $variable in ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to return an image when Ajax is done, but i don't know how to include a session variable in the response, this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#process").click(function(){

      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'process.php',
         success: function (msg) {
          $('#new-image').html('<img src="uploads/img/$_SESSION["sess_img"];" class="img-upload" alt="new image">')
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Then, I want show the image `$_SESSION["sess_img"];` within the div `#new-image`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can echo that image filename in `process.php` like this:

```
<?php
// using time() as the cache buster, the image will never be cache by the browser
// to solve it, you need to add condition that will check if the image has change or not.
// or maybe you need to change the filename if it changes without adding a cache buster.
echo $_SESSION['sess_img_chofer']."?v=".time();
```

And in your javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#process").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'process.php',
      success: function (image) {
        $('#new-image').html($('<img>').attr('src', 'uploads/img/' + image).attr('class', 'img-upload'));
      }
    }); 
  });
});
```

Comment: You should be more careful with the HTML injection. I'd go with something more like `$('#new-image').empty().append($('<img>').attr('src', 'uploads/img/' + image).attr('class', 'img-upload'))`

Comment: @vher2 This is well under way, the problem is that it does not update the new image, I have to give F5 to release the new, any ideas?

Comment: This is the old image `$_SESSION['sess_img']`?

Comment: @vher2 I have the image on the server, show the original on the div, then with proccess.php broken image and have to show the new image (it is rotated directly on the server with PHP) image if it is rotating, everything works fine, but the div is not updated, leaving the old to the photo view, if I F5 if you leave the new.

Comment: You have this two session variables `$_SESSION['sess_img']` and `$_SESSION["sess_img_chofer"]`. If I'm correct the last one is the new image. You can just change to that in `processs.php`

Comment: @vher2 No no, my question is wrong both are the same variable in question change the words to make them more understood, I forgot to correct the second, but we update the question. It is the same, so far everything works fine, except that the browser updates the image only by F5 this guess for temporary files, I just need to get the div is updated when I finish ajax like F5 it were.

Comment: Even if you click this button `$("#process")`, the image is not updated? That's what your code is doing, when it clicks it calls `process.php` and returns the image filename. What is it you want to do, you want it to run in background? so that you won't have to press F5?

Comment: I fixed it by putting: echo $_SESSION['sess_img']."?v=".time();